# How to get the variables in routing in zend framework 1.12

Tags: zend-framework, routes, url-routing, custom-routes

I am new to routing in zf. I don't understand some terms in route

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'author/:username',
     array(
    'controller' => 'profile',
    'action'     => 'userinfo'
      )
    );
```

$router->addRoute('user', $route);

How do we get `:username` here? from where do we get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username here is parameter pass by the user. So correct link using this route will be `http://somepage.com/author/John`. In your controller you can get this variable just like POST and GET variables - `$this->getParam('author');`

If you want to allow user use link without parameter (default parameter) you can add to array - `'author' => null` (i usually use this in pagination)

Comment: Thanks for the xplanation. Now I could understand the what the parameters are. But could you please tell me that use can give any value for :username

Comment: should work with _getParam("username", "john smiff")